# Heap (Priority queue) without duplicates in Golang

Tags: go, data-structures, duplicates, priority-queue, heap

I found that std lib [package heap](https://pkg.go.dev/container/heap@go1.20.1) contains interface for heap which could contains duplicates by default.
But what if I don't want to store duplicates in my heap? How can I handle this situation without using extra-memory?
Only one way I found is to check is heap contains element before pushing:

```golang
import "container/heap"

type PriorityQueue []int

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    if !pq.contains(x) {
        *pq = append(*pq, x.(int)))
    }
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) contains(x interface{}) bool {
// some checking contains func
}
```

Is any way to check it more elegant? Or other data structure (in std lib) with ordered elements and without duplicates with adding new element for *O log n*?

Comment: A slice combined with a map can work at amortized O(1)

Answer (score 2):

I don't use golang, so I can't give a code implementation, but here's a verbal description of a couple of possible solutions.

Binary heaps do not prevent duplicates, and since the internal ordering is only partially ordered they can be in completely different subtrees, i.e., not adjacent. However, duplicates will be adjacent once one of them percolates up to the root position. Consequently, you could write a wrapper function for popping values which does the following operations:

1. Pop a value off the heap
2. Peek at the new root

   - If it matches the first popped item, pop and discard it, then repeat step 2
   - Otherwise, return the popped value

In other words, throw away duplicates at retrieval time at a cost of O(log n) per duplicate, rather than at insertion time. If duplicates are relatively sparse, this would be fairly efficient.

If each value has two or more duplicate occurrences on average, you'd do better to keep a hash table of values in the heap. Before inserting, check the hash table to see if a value is already there and discard it if so. On popping, delete the corresponding entry in the hash table. This doubles the storage requirements relative to maintaining one data structure, but the additional computational requirements are negligible due to the O(1) complexity of hash operations.

Comment: your answer is valid but I assumed that some data structure already implemented in golang std lib. Thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

Golang doesn't have sets. But you could use a map in stead of a slice.

Something like:

```
type PriorityQueue map[int]bool

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x int) {
    if !pq[x] {
        pq[x] = true
    }
}
```